# Run vue project getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost error

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, nuxt.js

I have initialized a nuxt project and when I try to run it with npm run dev or yarn dev command it returns this error :

```
    build [==================  ] 91%Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Any idea where does it come from ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add 127.0.0.1   localhost to /etc/hosts

Comment: For me its already present there and It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is already any service running on that host and port. In my case,  I was trying to run it on port 80 while nginx is started.